# Using only once and start from beginning again

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have 500 usernames in my database. For each username in my database, I want to start from the first username, and call a function 10 times.

So example,

1. username1 - function called.
2. username2- function called.
3. username3- function called.
4. username4- function called.
5. username5- function called.
6. username6- function called.
7. username7- function called.
8. username8- function called.
9. username9- function called.
10. username10- function called.

Now we left off at username10, if I wanted to continue from username10 another day, how can I do this? I know you can add a new column to the database saying used and set it to '1' but, what if I did all 500, and want to start back over from username1 again? How can I do this?

Also when I am calling a function for each username, how can I log the process like above into a iframe?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the "used" column method, here's how you set every user to unused:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `used`=0;
```

I don't know what you mean by "log it to an iframe", but you could log all of the operations to a file, with fwrite - [here's the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

**Edit:**

```
Select all entries from table that have `checked`=0. For each of these entries
    Execute the functions you need to execute
    Set `checked`=1
```

When you want to start over

```
Set `checked`=0 for all entires. Execute code above.
```

Comment: Yes, I know but what if I want to use them again and start back over from username1?

Comment: @dustin: Then I suppose when `SELECT id FROM users WHERE used=0` returns no records you can run the UPDATE statement that @vladh supplied to start over.